# php - A session has been confirmed unset on one page. But when I go to another page, the session still hasn't been unset. What happen?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

For page one (`riderPage.php`), I have the following code.

```
<form action="riderJoinProcess.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');" class = "joinForm">
<input type = hidden name = id value="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" >
<input type =submit  class="edit_btn "  name = submit value = "Join" id = "<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>">
</form>
```

And then for page 2 (`riderJoinProcess.php`), I did some backend script in order to collect and store the data while setting the `SESSION['postId']`.

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'databaseConnection.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $_SESSION['postId'] = $_POST['id'];
    $post_id = $_SESSION['postId'];
    $sqlCommand4 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$post_id' ;" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCommand4);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result) ;
    }
    if ($results['post_numberOfPassenger'] >= 5) {
        $number = $results['post_numberOfPassenger'];

        echo '<script>alert ("The taxi is full already.") ; location.href = "riderPage.php" ; </script>';

    } else {
    $newNumberOfPassenger = $results['post_numberOfPassenger'] + 1;
    $sqlCommand5 = "UPDATE posts SET post_numberOfPassenger = '$newNumberOfPassenger' WHERE  post_id = '$post_id' ; " ;
    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCommand5);      
    echo '<script>location.href = "riderJoin.php" ; </script>';     
    }
}
```

At last, for page 3 (`riderJoin.php`), I have the following code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'databaseConnection.php';
if(isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['del'];
    $sqlCommand4 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$post_id' ;" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCommand4);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result) ;
    }

    $newNumberOfPassenger = $results['post_numberOfPassenger'] - 1;
    $sqlCommand5 = "UPDATE posts SET post_numberOfPassenger = '$newNumberOfPassenger' WHERE  post_id = '$post_id' ; " ;
    mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCommand5);
        unset($_SESSION['postId']);             
echo '<script> location.href = "riderPage.php" ; </script>';

} 
?>


<?php session_start();
    include 'databaseConnection.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['postId'])) {   ?>
```

So, my problem here is, the `$_SESSION['postId']` should be unset right after the `$_GET['del']` is set (AND IT DID UNSET ON PAGE 3 ONLY). But then when the browser redirects to the first page, the `$_SESSION['postId']` has not been unset. What's wrong here? I am a noob to programming, sorry for some stupid mistakes. Thanks

Comment: add this after **unset($_SESSION['postId']);**   `session_unset();` and `session_destroy();`

Comment: @ RïshïKêsh Kümar   Thanks for your reply. But I have other session variables too. I just want to unset the postId in particular. What can I do?

Comment: session_destroy — Destroys all data registered to a session

session_unset — Free all session variables

Comment: check your cache clear your cache

Comment: It is still not working. Can someone please help?

Comment: @YeungHarry: try this after the `unset`:  `session_write_close()`

Comment: @Paul T. The session is unset successfully on page 3 only. When I go back to page 1, the session appears again. Why is that?

Comment: @YeungHarry: ok, then try this instead. Rather than the `script` output that you have now, **after** the `unset` and `session_write_close();` add two more statements: `header('Location: riderPage.php');` and `exit();`.

Comment: @Paul T. No it's still not working.

Comment: @YeungHarry: ...so what else is in the code for `riderPage.php`, since only the form is shown above?

Comment: first of all I wouldn't call `session_start()` twice in the same script ...